# A Rumor about EF projects

Tags: entity-framework

I have heard that projects that use EF as their ORM mostly fail when they have huge databases and actually objects that are dealing with several mappings at the same time. Is it true that EF is still not quite ready for big enterprises?

Comment: This looks like a flame bait to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Whoever said that didn't spend too much time working with EF.  I've worked on/been involved with several projects using EF with very complex database schemas and large amounts of data and we had no issues outside of your normal problems you encounter with any ORM.